# Nuget Package from a Class Library Required in Main Project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget, class-library

I have created a Data Access Layer as a Class Library.  This class library has a nuget package installed for my ORM.  When I try to use my Class Library in my main project it complains that the main project doesn't have my ORM Nuget Package installed.

I thought that if the Class Library had that Nuget Package installed then I wouldn't need that package installed for every project that uses it.

Am I doing something wrong here or is that just the way it works?

Thanks!

***UPDATE***

In my DAL I have a DataRepositoryBase class that has a method called GetPaged.  Under the covers this DataRepositoryBase class uses ServiceStack's ORMLite.

In my Program I have the following code:

```
using (DataRepositoryBase<Inventory> InvRepo = new DataRepositoryBase<Inventory>())
        {
            IEnumerable<Inventory> invList = InvRepo.GetPaged(i => i.Cust_ID == CustID, 0, 10);
        }
```

My main program is complaining about not having a reference to ORMLite.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing types in the DAL from the Main Project then you have to reference that assembly from there as well.